# Get data from SQL Server C#

Tags: c#, sqlclient

I'm newbie in C#
I have 2 methods
In the first method, I want to get the result of the execution sql query - this number (for example 123456) and insert the number (123456) into the text field (second method)
but I do not get the result of running sql query
I use  System.Data.SqlClient;
Correct my code please.

```
//Method for retrieving data from a sql query

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Qry;
    Qry = "select number from TableTest "; 
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Qry, sqlConn))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            GetNumber(reader.GetString(2));
        }
        Application.Exit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error.Form_Clicker_1_Load" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Correct my code please."  So demanding. Are you being tested, or is this for fun? Choose wisely >:)

Comment: That Application.Exit(); will not help things. `Y2` is unlikely to be a tag name.  Recalling the method in catch() is not the thing to do.  GetString(2) is not correct as there is only one field in the select list.  What if there is more than one row in the table?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `Read()` method. Try like:

```
..
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
   GetNumber(reader[2].ToString());
}
..
```

Comment: SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
   GetNumber(reader[2].GetString());
}